# Twitter Bootstrap Delayed CSS Effects

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I extended the CSS template provided by Bootstrap with a custom.css file. However, I noticed that upon loading the site, there's a split second when you can see the old CSS provided by bootstrap and then the site adjusts itself with the new CSS.

I find this distracting for the user to have the fonts / position of divs constantly changing. How do web developers combat this with Bootstrap? I understand that you don't to directly modify the Bootstrap CSS files as this produces issues when updates arrive.

For reference :

```
 <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining all 3 CSS files into 1 would be one solution. There are all sorts of ways of doing this. The low-tech method would be to start a new **combined.css** file, then copy and paste your 3 CSS files into this new file. Best to do this in the same order as they currently appear. Then in the head of your file, replace the three CSS file links with

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/combined.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You may also marginally speed up the page loading as well because you are now loading just the one file.

If you want to take it one step further, try minifying your combined CSS. Again there are all sorts of options, one possibility is http://www.cssminifier.com

Good luck

Comment: One can take this idea one step further by using the .less files and adding your custom css as as .less file. Then, all of the .less files get compiled. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap

Comment: Yes I agree @Scott, less is brilliant. A bit more of a learning curve but definitely worth it.